# Mummy is talking with who?

Tags: sentence-construction

He saw his mother speaking in the phone.

> "Who is mummy talking?"
>
> "Mummy is talking with who?"

Can the question rephrase as the second one?

Comment: Your second version is "valid", but *very* unlikely (particularly from a child, since it's syntactically complex). Your first version isn't valid at all though - it must include a preposition: *Who is Mummy talking **with**?* (or more likely, *Who is Mummy talking **to**?*).

Comment: A couple other minor corrections:  his mother was speaking **on** the phone, and you want to ask "Can the question **be rephrased**..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that both sentences are incorrect. They lack the preposition and the use of the relative pronoun is not correct.

"Who is mummy talking?", should be "Whom is mummy talking to?"/"To whom is mummy talking?"

WHILE

"Mummy is talking with who?", should be "Mummy is talking to/with whom?".

I've learnt that when using who+preposition, whom is the adequate option. But I am not a native speaker.

I am an ESL teacher and every book we use teaches the "whom" case. Always emphasising its old-fashioned use, though, along with other examples as the use of elder/eldest, ou even the reading of numbers. Spoken everyday-English may be different from what scholars teach, but the use of whom is certainly the most correct when a preposition is dependent on. Whom are you speaking to? sounds more awkward than To whom are you speaking?, but both are correct. Even if it isn't much used.

Comment: Technically, you are correct; it should be *whom*.  But in practice, almost nobody says *whom* anymore; it's always *who*.

Comment: @stangdon Nope.  If almost nobody says *whom* anymore, then "it should be *whom*" is incorrect as a description of the English language.  It doesn't help to spread the myth that the way everyone speaks Standard English is somehow incorrect.

Comment: @snailplane - Well, I think we're getting a little philosophical now.  I certainly wouldn't say "whom" is *wrong*, and just because many people don't use it (regularly) doesn't make it wrong, just perhaps an incomplete description.  But English(es) cover a lot of ground and it's almost impossible to give a complete description.

Comment: @stangdon On the flip side of that, just because people used to speak a certain way, doesn't make it more correct than the modern usage. Part of what makes English so difficult to learn is that we keep changing the rules ;)

Comment: @stangdon I don't have any reason to refute your comment, but I need to clarify something since you appear to have misunderstood.  Using *whom* isn't wrong, and I wouldn't and didn't make that claim.  What is wrong is the claim that "it should be *whom*", which is incorrect as a description of the English language.

Comment: @snailplane - How is saying "**technically**, it should be *whom*" incorrect, especially since it was followed up with "in practice, almost nobody says whom anymore"?  I never said "saying *who* is incorrect".

Answer (score 1):

The following forms are correct:

> Who is Mummy talking to?
>
> Who's Mummy talking to?
>
> Who is Mummy talking with?
>
> Who's Mummy talking with?

"To" sounds more idiomatic here.

The following sounds somewhat awkward:

> Mummy is talking to who?

The only time we would be likely to say that would be if we were emphasising the word "who" and expressing surprise:

> (A:) Mummy's talking to Uncle Bob.
>
> (B:) Mummy's talking to *who*?  [She never talks to Uncle Bob!]

*Note*: The word "whom" has been mentioned.  The "whom" forms are correct formal usage (but most people would consider "who" equally correct, and almost everyone would consider "who" acceptable in all but the most formal contexts).  Admittedly, even informal usage doesn't always tolerate "who" directly after a preposition - but the above example would be an exception to that.

There are some English speakers who avoid "whom" altogether.  Others use it in at least some circumstances.  However, in a child's speech, particularly since the sentence uses the informal term "Mummy", it's unlikely that the word "whom" would be used.